# How to configure braintree webhooks for localhost

Tags: braintree

I'm trying to configure braintree webhooks for localhost. It's showing destination not verified. I even tried using Ultrahook to get a public facing url but still not working with braintree. The same url works with other apps

Comment: Found the solution.

1. Download ngrok from https://ngrok.com/
2. Unzip it and then run it
3. Then type following command ngrok yourportnumber (e.g. ngrok 50871)
4. The it will give you new forwading adrress something like http://555a0898.ngrok.com
5. Go to braintree and use this new address and viola your are done.

Comment: I work at Braintree. Glad you were able to get this working. If you need more help, please feel free to [reach out to our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).

Comment: Ultrahook is only for receiving webhooks, it merely responds to every request with a 200 status and blank page. `ngrok` as you mentioned works perfectly, though you have to update the webhook destination every time you restart `ngrok` unless you sign up to get subdomains.

Comment: @agf You guys should definitely add ngrok to the documentation on Braintree

Comment: Look at this question it will surely help     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234356/test-webhook-at-localhost-in-braintree

Comment: Hm, but you'll have to change the URL every time you restart ngrok ^^

Comment: https://srv.us doesn't have this limitation :) Disclaimer: I built and operate it.